# Spring Data Specification for set contains operation

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, criteria-api

I have two entities, `A` and `B`. There is many-to-many relationship between them, where `A` hold a list of `B`. *How to write a Specification to retrieve all `A` entites that contains `B` with specific name?* Example:

```
@Service
public class YourService {

    @Resource
    private ARepository repository;

    // I know how to do this type of queries with specifications
    public List<A> getByB(B b) {
        return repository.findAll(Specifications.containsB(b));
    }

    //Question: how to write Specification for this type of query?
    public List<A> getByNameOfB(String name) {
         return repository.findAll(Specifications.containsBWithName(name));
    }
}
```

Entities:

```
@Entity
public class B {

        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "B_SEQ", name = "BSeq", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "BSeq")
        private Long id;

        @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
        private String name;
}

@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "A_SEQ", name = "ASeq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ASeq")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "A_B",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<B> bList;
}
```

Metamodels:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(A.class)
public class A_ {
    public static volatile ListAttribute<A, B> bList;
}


@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(B.class)
public class B_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<B, String> name;
}
```

Retrieval:

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<A> {
}

public class Specifications {

    public static Specification<A> containsB(B b) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            Expression<List<B>> bList = root.get(A_.bList);
            return cb.isMember(b, bList);
        };
    }

    // HERE IS A QUESTION:

    public static Specification<A> containsBWithName(String name) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            ListJoin<List<B>> bList = root.join(A_.bList);
            Expression<String> exp = bList.get(B_.name)
            //TODO how to check that name is one of the retrieved names?
            //PROBLEM, method below expects Expression<List<String>> instead of Expression<String>
            cb.isMember(name, exp); 
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to do next:

```
public static Specification<A> containsBWithName(String name) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        root.join("bList", JoinType.INNER);
        return cb.equal(root.get("bList").get("name"), name);
    };
}
```

Hope it will do the trick.

Spring Data version **1.11.4**

Answer (score 9):

It took me some time to figure out why the accepted answer didn't work for me.
I had to do it this way:

```
public static Specification<A> containsBWithName(String name) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        Join<Object, Object> bListJoin = root.join("bList", JoinType.INNER);
        return cb.equal(bListJoin.get("name"), name);
    };
}
```

Spring Data 1.11.9

Comment: This answer works for me instead of the accepted one. spring data 2.14